# Checking Symmetry in Polar Equations

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Let's say we want to check whether a polar graph is symmetric about the origin.

Then

- if $(-r,\theta)$ satifies the polar equation for the graph whenever $(r,\theta)$ satisfies the graph, it is symmetric about the origin
- or if $(r,\theta+\pi)$ satifies the polar equation for the graph whenever $(r,\theta)$ satisfies the graph, it is symmetric about the origin.

But $r=3\sin(2\theta)$ is symmetric about the origin and $(r,\theta+\pi)$ satisfies the euqation but $(-r,\theta)$ does not satisfy the equation.

I was wondering if there is an example where $(-r,\theta)$ satisfies the euqation but $(r,\theta+\pi)$ does not satisfy the equation.

Comment: You have to be careful with the definition of $r$. In your example, $r$ can be negative but in polar coordinates, $r$ is always non-negative.

Comment: What is a negative radius?